# Selection Limit on CheckboxBar

Tags: manipulate, dynamic

Is there an easy way to limit the number of selections in a CheckboxBar such that at any time you can choose only two options. I tried to use the "Enabled" option, but that grays out the whole checkboxBar. How can access individual Checkbox in CheckboxBar (so that, I can disable only those Checkboxes that are not selected) ?

```
Manipulate[NumSelec, {NumSelec, {1, 2, 3, 4}, ControlType -> CheckboxBar,  Enabled -> If[Length[NumSelec] >= 2, False, True]}]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the second argument to `Dynamic`. Example:

```
DynamicModule[{NumSelec = {}},
 Column[{
   CheckboxBar[
    Dynamic[NumSelec, (If[Length[#] > 2, NumSelec = #[[-2 ;;]], 
        NumSelec = #]) &], {1, 2, 3, 4}],
   Dynamic[NumSelec]
   }]
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is one way using `DynamicModule`

```
 DynamicModule[{NumSelec1 = {}, NumSelec2 = {}, NumSelec3 = {}, false},
 Column[{
   Dynamic@
    Row[{CheckboxBar[Dynamic[NumSelec1], {1}, 
       Enabled -> (NumSelec1 =!= {} || false)], 
      CheckboxBar[Dynamic[NumSelec2], {2}, 
       Enabled -> (NumSelec2 =!= {} || false)], 
      CheckboxBar[Dynamic[NumSelec3], {3}, 
       Enabled -> (NumSelec3 =!= {} || false)]}],
   Dynamic[false = (Length[join] < 2); 
    join = Join[NumSelec1, NumSelec2, NumSelec3]]
   }]
 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using a function to rewrite the dynamic value when length of 2 is exceeded.

```
Manipulate[
 NumSelec = limit[NumSelec, 2], {NumSelec, {1, 2, 3, 4}, ControlType -> CheckboxBar}, 
 Initialization :> (
  limit[x_, num_] := If[ListQ[x], If[Length[x] > num, x[[-num ;;]], x], x])
]
```