# Checkboxbar with maximum choices limitation

Tags: dynamic, interface, interactive

I am a novice to interactive interface with Dynamic and other stuff. So don't blame on me if I ask idiot questions.

What I want is to set a checkbox and set a limitation for the maximal number that choices can be checked. For example, say I have a checkboxbar like:

```
CheckboxBar[Dynamic[x],{1,2,3,4}]
```

Now I am able to check as many choices as I like. But what if I only want to check at most two box? Is there a way to let me check the first two boxes and then the remaining unchecked one will automatically become gray(not clickable, just like the option:Enabled->False)

My naive idea was:

```
CheckboxBar[Dynamic[x],{1,2,3,4},Enabled->If[Length@x<2,True,False]]
```

But it doesn't work.

Thanks for your time! Any comments and suggestions are very welcome.

Comment: You have to add `Dynamic` to the argument of `Enabled`, i.e. `CheckboxBar[Dynamic[x], {1, 2, 3, 4}, Enabled :> Dynamic[Length@x < 3]]`

Comment: Maybe this would work for you? `CheckboxBar[
 Dynamic[x, (x = Reverse[Take[Reverse[#], UpTo[2]]]) &], {1, 2, 3, 4}]`

Comment: @Kuba♦ , Thanks! This is a quite clever way!

Comment: Is this a duplicate or do you need something more? [Selection Limit on CheckboxBar](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/105953/5478)

Comment: @Kuba I think it could be a duplicate of that one.

Answer (score 3):

You almost got it right. This should do what you want:

```
CheckboxBar[Dynamic[x], {1, 2, 3, 4}, Enabled -> Dynamic[Length[x] < 3]]
```

Besides the `Dynamic` after `Enabled`, which is the thing that makes everything work, I also shortened your `If` statement, using that `Length[x] < 3` already returns either `True` or `False` (unless you do something strange with `x` -- if that can happen, you may want to wrap `Length[x] < 3` into `TrueQ`).
To re-enable the bar once it was disabled, you could add a `Button` to your notebook, such as

```
Button["Reset", x = {}]
```

### Addendum

Following up on your comment. A `CheckboxBar` where only the checkboxes get disabled that would, when clicked, exceed the limit, can be built from individual `Checkbox`es, e.g.:

```
With[{labels = {"a", "b", "c", "d"}},
  DynamicModule[{x, arr, bar, n = Length[labels]},
    x = Array[arr, n];
    bar = (
      Checkbox[Dynamic[#],
        Enabled -> Dynamic[
          Count[Table[arr[i], {i, n}], True] < 2 || TrueQ[#]
        ]
      ] & /@ x
    );
    (* initialize *)
    Do[arr[i] = False, {i, n}];
    (* return the bar *)
    Row[Riffle[bar, labels], Spacer[10]]
  ]
]
```

[image: dynamic checkbox-bar output]

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer! It does work. But I am sorry, I forgot to say one thing, that is once it is disabled, all the choices are disabled, which is not my intention. I expect it to only disable the remaining unchecked one, so that I can change my choices later if I check the wrong box by clicking again to un-check. Would it be possible? I tried something like Enable->{True,True,False,False} but it seems there is no such grammar to assign the checkability separately.

Comment: You should add this to your question.